# Wix install with multiple services, and I don't how many

Tags: wix

I need to install my windows service, and have at least one instance of it. The user decides how many services they will have. But which approach will I take?

- Try to make my ServiceInstall foreach the number of windows services or install them with an customization via installutil?

and then I have to solve so it does not install duplicates. But I can make an xml file that contains the service names to be installed, and read from there.

But I have read that people don't like using foreach in wix because it complicates stuff much more, and some people say installutil isn't good either. But since I don't know how many services it will be I have to solve it something like this.

And with installutil i won't get rollback either?

Does anyone know another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run custom action which patches your MSI including service elements to install. This approach allows you to read service names from wherever you want and install as many services as you need.

Though it would be quite non-trivial for those who read your installer source code later. And to be honest I've never used this approach. But it should work...

Comment: hmm yes and if i access that same ServiceInstall element through customActions, that will probably give me more response back too if it fails or succeeds then installutil.

Comment: yes, it will behave exactly as if you have specified every ServiceInstall element on your own. So you are guaranteed to have error-handling and rollback functionality

Comment: i admit this sounds like the best choice right now :) i will test this and reply my results

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            if (System.Environment.UserInteractive)
            {
                string parameter = string.Concat(args);
                switch (parameter)
                {
                    case "install":
                        ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                        break;
                    case "uninstall":
                        ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { "/u", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ServiceBase.Run(new WindowsService());
            }
        }
    }
```

making my service installable and uninstallable on its own and then made customactions to install and uninstall them